# Rotating skirt effect, possible with cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I wonder if the [rotating skirt effect](https://youtu.be/NK7iIBcsBn4?t=9) is possible with cloth simulation.

[image]

I tried that and from the 100's frame I rotated the body, but the cloth did not rotate even though I pinned the cloth to the cylinder. The file can be [downloaded from here](https://filebin.net/6766h0szop6uty6u/anna.blend?t=cyl3evkl).

PS: I followed the answer and got a similar effect, though crude.

[image]

Comment: Adding more lines made the cloth fluctuate and the body rotated, but still the cloth itself is not moving with the body. It seems that the cloth is not actually glued to the body, but attached to some imaginary points that share the same location with the body. https://imgur.com/6J0ALSE

Comment: @cegaton It took a lot of work to workaround this site's limitation, but I embedded the animation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cloth to follow an object:

You make a vertex group of the vertices of your cloth, that you want to stick to the body. In the cloth simulation you choose that vertex group for the pinning.

Then you parent the Cloth to the Body (select cloth, then while holding shift select the body, then press control + P, then choose "set parent to Object".

When you now move/rotate the object, the pinned vertices will stay on the same position of the object, and the rest will be simulated.

Answer (score 5):

Think of the geometry of the image you uploaded:

[image]

You need more subdivisions on the fabric. Faces don't curve, bend or twist. **The edges will always be straight**. To create any kind of curvature you need subdivisions. The extra geometry will allow you to create the transitions and facilitate the different folds and twists of the fabric that you show in the reference image.

[image]

An example of possible topology to play with:

[image]

Step by step

Make a **Vertex Group** and assign it to the top loop.

Add a **Hook > Hook to New Object**. A new empty is created, and the vertex group is now controlled by it. The idea is that only the pinned vertices move independently than the rest of the fabric, and they pull the rest of the surfaces as they move. By moving the empty you can do that now.

Add a Cloth modifier to the object, and make the vertex group the Pin Group.

(note that the order of the modifiers matters here.)

[image]

For a softer surface you might want to add a subsurf modifier at the bottom of the stack.

Animate the rotation of the empty (or parent the empty to the body of the dancer)

The quality of the simulation depends largely on the **quality steps**. Play with the weight, stiffness, damping, tension and shear of the fabric until you are happy ever after.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1, Yeah its important to increase the quality of the simulation and play with the cloth settings to get a good looking result.

Answer (score -2):

Cloth sim gives good shape key timing while animation.

Comment: do you mind [edit]ing to expand your explanation? check [answer].